# Tinkerpop value of list property is returned as string instead of list

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I am trying to store a list in a vertex property. That seems to work but when I try to get the list it is returned as string instead of list. This happens both in python-gremlin and on the gremlin-console. What am I doing wrong?

```
gremlin> my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
==>a
==>b
==>c
gremlin> g.V(213168).property("vert_prop_list", my_list).iterate()
gremlin> g.V(213168).values("vert_prop_list")
==>[a, b, c]
gremlin> g.V(213168).values("vert_prop_list").next().class
==>class java.lang.String  //I would have expected List here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might have something to do with the graph database you're using. With TinkerGraph, it works as expected:

```
gremlin> my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
==>a
==>b
==>c
gremlin> g.V(1).property("vert_prop_list", my_list).iterate()
gremlin> g.V(1).values("vert_prop_list")
==>[a,b,c]
gremlin> g.V(1).values("vert_prop_list").next().class
==>class java.util.ArrayList
gremlin> g.V(1).values("vert_prop_list").unfold()
==>a
==>b
==>c
```

If the graph you are using utilizes a schema it's possible that you haven't specified the the data type properly or perhaps the graph does not support lists at all and it is simply doing a `toString()` on any data type it doesn't recognize.

Comment: The graph is JanusGraph and the schema specification for the property is list.